# Cascading dropdown lists in SP 2013 without InfoPath or JavaScript

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

The problem that I have is that due to security restrictions it is not possible to use JavaScript code or SharePoint Designer to implement cascading Dropdown lists in a list form. InfoPath doesn’t work good, because the list was modified in XSL Designer. 
Does anyone have an idea how to implement cascading Dropdowns without any tools? I appreciate any help! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is not a OOTB way to achieve it.

We have to use custom code to achieve it. As you can't use JavaScript, you can create a custom column using a farm solution in SharePoint 2013 to achieve it.

Here is a custom lookup field solution with source code for your reference.

[SharePoint 2013 Filtered Lookup Field](https://github.com/hasangok/sharepoint-2013-filtered-lookup-field)

Comment: I modify the reply in above.